# minimum RGB path

Tags: algorithm, graph

You are given a *directed* graph `G = (V, E)` *weighted edges*. Nodes are colored red, green and blue.
A path from **s** to **v** is called colorful if it contains red green and a blue node.

find the shortest path between **s** and every **v**, in condition that the path should be colorful.
If there is more than one path that is colorful find the minimum between them.

If there is no such a path return false.

I'm not sure how to get started on this. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This seems a task for Dijkstra's algorithm with the added ending condition that the path should be colorful. Have a go at it, and if you bump into a *specific* question, come back with that.

Comment: Are the weights non-negative?

Comment: yes the weights are non-negative.

Comment: with adding the condition that the path should be colorful then i am changing the  algorithm. 
and i cant figure a way how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

As you walk along a path from *s* to *v*, go from one "state" to another, where the "state" includes both the node you are on *and* which colors of nodes you've been on in your journey (7 possible combinations).  Your state determines which paths from your current position are valid solutions.

From your original graph, make (or imagine) a graph of accessible states, where an edge represents the ability to transition from one state to the next.  This graph will have up to 7 vertices for each of the original graph vertices.

Now use Dijkstra's algorithm to find the shortest path from *(s,red)* (assuming s is red) to (*v,red+green+blue)*